# SQL Server query for new and repeat orders per month

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, datepart

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2 and having a hard time gathering new vs repeat customer orders.

I have data in this format:

```
OrderID     OrderDate   Customer    OrderAmount
-----------------------------------------------
1           1/1/2017    A           $10
2           1/2/2017    B           $20
3           1/3/2017    C           $30
4           4/1/2017    C           $40
5           4/2/2017    D           $50
6           4/3/2017    D           $60
7           1/6/2018    B           $70
```

Here's what we want:

- New defined as: customer has not placed any orders in any prior months.
- Repeat defined as: customer has placed an order in a prior month (even if many years ago).

This means that if a new customer places multiple orders in her first month, they would all be considered "new" customer orders. And orders placed in subsequent months would all be considered "repeat" customer orders.

We want to get New orders (count and sum) and Repeat orders (count and sum) per year, per month:

```
Year    Month   NewCount        NewSum          RepeatCount         RepeatSum
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017    1       3 (A,B,C)       $60 (10+20+30)  0                   $0
2017    4       2 (D,D)         $110 (50+60)    1 (C)               $40 (40)
2018    1       0               $0              1 (B)               $70 (70)
```

(*The info in () parenthesis is not part of the result; just putting it here for clarity*)

The SQL is easy to write for any single given month, but I don't know how to do it when gathering years worth of months at a time...

If there is a month with no orders of any kind then NULL or 0 values for the year:month would be preferred.

Comment: Take a look at Window Functions and `LEAD()` and `LAG()`.

Comment: From what I can tell Lead and Lag are not available on 2008R2.

Comment: @BillyTurtleneck You're right, they are not available. But are you aware the final end of life for Sql Server 2008 R2 is only about a year away? No new patches will be created for that version of Sql Server after July 9, 2019....  not even critical security patches. It's time to start your migration project for a more recent version.

Comment: That's a good point. But is it fruitless to try to do this without using Lead/Lag, or is there a way it can be done? Currently I'm using loops in my web app code and it is slow. If I can get it all from SQL the way I need it in a single query to the db that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank` to find new and old customers. This query returns your provided output

```
declare @t table (OrderID int, OrderDate date, Customer char(1), OrderAmount int)
insert into @t
values  (1, '20170101', 'A', 10)
    , (2, '20170102', 'B', 20), (3, '20170103', 'C', 30)
    , (4, '20170401', 'C', 40), (5, '20170402', 'D', 50)
    , (6, '20170403', 'D', 60), (7, '20180106', 'B', 70)

select
    [year], [month], NewCount = isnull(sum(case when dr = 1 then 1 end), 0)
    , NewSum = isnull(sum(case when dr = 1 then OrderAmount end), 0)
    , RepeatCount = isnull(sum(case when dr > 1 then 1 end), 0)
    , RepeatSum = isnull(sum(case when dr > 1 then OrderAmount end), 0)
from (
    select 
        *, [year] = year(OrderDate), [month] = month(OrderDate)
        , dr = dense_rank() over (partition by Customer order by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, OrderDate), 0))
    from 
        @t
) t
group by [year], [month]
```

Output

```
year    month  NewCount   NewSum   RepeatCount   RepeatSum
----------------------------------------------------------
2017    1      3          60       0             0
2018    1      0          0        1             70
2017    4      2          110      1             40
```

You must get combination of each year in the table with all months at first if you want to display months without orders. Then join with upper query

```
select
    *
from
    (select distinct y = year(OrderDate) from @t) t
    cross join (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) q(m)
```

Comment: YES! This is perfect. Wow. Such an elegant and simple solution. This works great and gives exactly what I need. I figured that Over and Partition were part of it but hadn't considered Dense_Rank. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

First, start by summarizing the data with one record per customer per month.

Then, you can use a self-join or similar construct to get the information you need:

```
with cm as (
      select customer, dateadd(day, 1 - day(orderdate), orderdate) as yyyymm
             sum(orderamount) as monthamount, count(*) as numorders
      from orders
      group by customer
     )
select year(cm.yyyymm) as yr, month(cm.yyyymm) as mon,
       sum(case when cm.num_orders > 0 and cm_prev.customer is null then 1 else 0 end) as new_count,
       sum(case when cm.num_orders > 0 and cm_prev.customer is null then monthamount else 0 end) as new_amount,
       sum(case when cm.num_orders > 0 and cm_prev.customer > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as repeat_count,
       sum(case when cm.num_orders > 0 and cm_prev.customer > 0 then monthamount else 0 end) as repeat_amount
from cm left join
     cm cm_prev
     on cm.customer = cm_prev.customer and
        cm.yyyymm = dateadd(month, 1, cm_prev.yyyymm)
group by year(cm.yyyymm), month(cm.yyyymm)
order by year(cm.yyyymm), month(cm.yyyymm);
```

This would be a bit easier in SQL Server 2012, where you can use `lag()`.

Comment: Do you mean to use month in line 2? I am getting error when trying to process that individual select statement.

Comment: I don't understand the "_prev"... Can you explain?

Comment: @BillyTurtleneck . . . Nothing is called `_prev` in the query, so I don't understand the question.  Line 2 is one standard way to get the first date of the month.